# codeigniter grouped by, products stock on separate branch

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

In codeigniter I have this on database:

```
product_id      product_name     stock     branch 
    1           shoe             5         New York
    1           shoe             10        Los Angeles
    1           shoe             5         Detroit
    2           shirt            10        New York
    2           shirt            5         Detroit
    3           skirt            7         Detroit
```

What I want to achieve is this table (in view):

```
product_id      product_name     stock     New York    Los Angeles     Detroit
    1           shoe             20           5           10             5
    2           shirt            15           10          -              5
    3           skirt            7            -           -              7
```

How to code in Codeigniter 3?

Comment: it is `Pivot Tables`

Answer (score 0):

First fire this query,

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, SUM(stock), 
GROUP_CONCAT(branch,"#@#",stock) branch_stock FROM your_table GROUP BY product_id
```

Then you will get array by firing this query.

```
foreach($array as $k => $v){
  $temp = explode("#@#", $v['branch_stock']);
  $array[$k][$temp[0]] = $temp[2];
}
```

For fetching all column names, you can do

```
$columns  = array_keys($array);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Model:

```
function product_stock(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select('SUM(case when branch = "New York" then stock else NULL end) as branch_ny');
$this->db->select('SUM(case when branch = "Los Angeles" then stock else NULL end) as branch_la');
$this->db->select('SUM(case when branch = "Detroit" then stock else NULL end) as branch_dt');
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->group_by("product_id");
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

}

in view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>Produk Id</th>
    <th>Produk Nama</th>
    <th>New York</th>
    <th>Los Angeles</th>
    <th>Detroit</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($allproduct as $e){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $e['product_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $e['product_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $e['branch_ny']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $e['branch_la']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $e['branch_dt']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

it works for me